# How to avoid blocking the screen while the app is active and downloaded files?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i do in a app in WP8 where i must downloaded a files , and saved in datebase the contents , but when i was doing test .... The files size is 17 megabytes , and scren lock , if the scren lock while the download is in progress stop it , Somebody has a idea that can i do ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a `BackgroundWorker` to do the heavy job. Here's an MSDN article that will get you started: [**How to use a background worker for Windows Phone**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Good one. Also it's useful to get familiar with Parallel Library, especially `Task` class. In order to not to lock UI, you must run operations **asynchronously** in other thread - it keeps the main thread free, as asynchorous callbacks instead of it get busy with long-lasting operations

Answer (score 1):

The Best thing to do in windows phone for file transfer is to use the the Background transfer API.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundtransfer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

This will allow your app to download big data files event if your application is closed or send to the background

Answer (score 0):

You can disable idle detection. You have all the information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
Remember to turn off after download.